# Android TV ImageViewCard Layout margin change

Tags: android, television, android-tv, presenter

I have been working on an android tv app.I have list of movies which i populated inside the `BrowserFragment` class.I have a presenter class that make use of `ImageCardView` to show the movie thumbnail.I am trying to customize the imagecardview on Selected.I wanted it to look like the pic here.On selection of particular `ImageCardView` the thumbnail will increase in size but the base alignment should be the same as the other unselected ones as shown in the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tms1C.png).

**EDIT** Pic Link https://www.dropbox.com/s/habpjnrlwh1se8v/sample.png?dl=0

**EDIT** Presenter class

```
public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {
private int mSelectedBackgroundColor = -1;
private int mDefaultBackgroundColor = -1;
private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;

class ViewHolder extends Presenter.ViewHolder {
    HashMap<Integer,Object> ObjectsList=new HashMap<>();
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    mDefaultBackgroundColor = R.color.default_background;
    mSelectedBackgroundColor = R.color.selected_background;
    mDefaultCardImage = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lb_card_shadow_focused, null);

    ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
            super.setSelected(selected);
        }
    };

    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}

private void updateCardBackgroundColor(ImageCardView view, boolean selected) {
    int color = selected ? mSelectedBackgroundColor : mDefaultBackgroundColor;

    // Both background colors should be set because the view's
    // background is temporarily visible during animations.

    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(color);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    Movie movie = (Movie) item;

    ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;
    cardView.setTitleText(movie.getName());
    cardView.setContentText(movie.getCategory());

    if (movie.getImgResUrl() != 0) {
        // Set card size from dimension resources.
        Resources res = cardView.getResources();
//            int width = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_width);
//            int height = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_height);
        cardView.setMainImageDimensions(300, 300);

        Glide.with(cardView.getContext())
                .load(movie.getImgResUrl())
                .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;

    // Remove references to images so that the garbage collector can free up memory.
    cardView.setBadgeImage(null);
    cardView.setMainImage(null);
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please add the reference image or Add the presenter class code which have image card view.

Comment: @jaydroider i dont have enough reputation to post image so i have added link to the sample image

Comment: Please post your presenter class code.

Comment: Currently with this code how is your list row layout is looking. Can you explain bit more ?

Comment: yes, i have rows of movie thumbnails which i can scroll down vertically .Each rows have different category like comedy , action adventure.Added these categories just for the name sake.

Comment: So basically you want to focus list row selected movie which will show some what large then other movies.

Comment: yes it should enlarge but as shown in the picture , the base of the enlarged picture should be the same(all in a straight line) as that of the other pics

Comment: Could you give reference image for how is your current layout looking with all movies.

Comment: Try with my answer this method is i have used in one of my TV app and it's working fine.

Comment: Anyone can help with this?. I also want the exact custom card http://i.stack.imgur.com/tms1C.png

Answer (score 1):

Try with this method.

**In your View Holder class Modify this.**

```
class ViewHolder extends Presenter.ViewHolder {
   private ImageCardView mCardView;
   private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;
   private PicassoImageCardViewTarget mImageCardViewTarget;
   HashMap<Integer,Object> ObjectsList=new HashMap<>();

   public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mCardView = (ImageCardView) view;
        mImageCardViewTarget = new PicassoImageCardViewTarget(mCardView);
    }

    protected void updateCardViewImage(URI uri) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uri.toString())
                .resize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(mContext, CARD_WIDTH),
                        Utils.convertDpToPixel(mContext, CARD_HEIGHT))
                .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                .into(mImageCardViewTarget);
    }
}
```

**Where card width and card height should be define Globally in presenter class.**

```
private static int CARD_WIDTH = 323;
private static int CARD_HEIGHT = 146;
```

**Then call this in onBindViewHolder like this.**

```
if (movie.getImgResUrl() != 0) {
    Resources res = cardView.getResources();
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mCardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).updateCardViewImage(movie.getCardImageURI());
}
```

**Don't Forget to add this in Build.Gradle file.**

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No , i haven't tried yet.I shifted my focus on fetching and consuming the web service.Once i finished it , i will try your idea and then let you know